# How to change windows control panel settings through C#

Tags: c#, dropshadow, controlpanel

More specifically I want to change Visual Effects. My goal is to press a button then have it change the 15 visual effects. Such as turning off "drop shadow" and disabling "fade/slide menus into view." I did a ton of searching and the only thing I accomplished is how to find out if it is enabled with something like this:

```
dropshadow = SystemInformation.IsDropShadowEnabled;
MessageBox.Show("Drop Shadow enabled:"+Convert.ToString(dropshadow));
```

This is for C#

Comment: `SystemParametersInfo(...)` with an action of `SPI_SETUIEFFECTS` might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to use pinvoke to achieve this.

Have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/97142
And here is a c# example http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.systemparametersinfo

Not sure if this covers everything you want, but should cover most.

This is what SystemInformation uses under the hood, I believe.

Comment: Good Answer. Just wanted to add that a more comprehensive list of specific systemparametersinfo settings [can be found on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)